# Frame drops in Gnome

Tags: gnome, graphics, intel-graphics

Sometimes, when I do some graphics-intensive tasks in my desktop PC, such as watching videos on YouTube or creating 3D models, after some time I can notice frame drops-- mouse cursor does not move smoothly and animations not occurring smoothly. Even during this, my computer is completely usable, only it loads programs slowly.
During this time, I open up the **gnome-system-monitor** and see that 4 processes--

- kidle_inj/0
- kidle_inj/1
- kidle_inj/2
- kidle_inj/3

are having too much CPU usage (about 20% or more). After leaving the computer for some time, these processes stop and again the speed becomes normal. This occurred with both Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04.
I managed to have a screenshot of the situation in case you need it for reference:
[image]

I think that my problem is unlike others because in this case the computer neither freeze completely nor do I need to restart my computer to get back to normal condition, it normalizes on its own after some time. What can be the reason for this and how to fix this issue?

FYI I have Intel Graphics 2500.

Comment: Using wayland got rid of slow desktop stuff for me on intel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched the internet and found out that this happens due to the processor becoming overheated, and the slowing down is a protective measure of the computer to prevent the processor from heating more, which can otherwise damage it.

I have installed `lm-sensors` and found out that whenever I do any CPU intensive tasks, the processor temperature goes above 90 degrees celsius and then my computer feels slow. When I leave it for some time, it automatically comes to normal condition after the temperature drops below 85 degrees celsius.

`lm-sensors` also revealed that the issue was actually with the CPU fan which was not spinning (0 RPM), which caused the processor to overheat. I had to replace the CPU fan and after that, the problem was gone. So, anybody having this problem should check the CPU temperature from the BIOS screen or by using `lm-sensors` to find where the issue is.